# SQL Server -> Sybase

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sybase

Can you please help me convert this T-SQL SQL Servers to Sybase compatible sytax

I've been googling it but can't find anything, I'm prob searching for keywords that don't exist in Sybase!

Here is what I trying to convert

```
CREATE LOGIN bcpuser WITH PASSWORD = 'bcppassword'

CREATE USER bcpuser FOR LOGIN bcpuser"

sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'bcpuser'
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create Login

```
sp_addlogin bcpuser, bcppassword
```

To Grant Role

```
sp_role "grant", sa_role, bcpuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Raymund has provided most of it.  Same as MS< User is at the db level.

```
    sp_adduser login_name
```